# I have been trying to figure out how to make video of selected images with FFmpeg

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

I am working with Android videos and  I know how to determine the series  of images using gallary View. But I'm stuck on FFmpeg now.

With the below code I am getting some images from gallery:

```
btnSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  public void onClick(View v) {
    final int len = thumbnailsselection.length;
    int cnt = 0;
    String selectImages = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (thumbnailsselection[i]) {
        cnt++;
        selectImages = selectImages + arrPath[i] + "|";
      }
    }

    if (cnt == 0) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select at least one image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {

      Log.d("SelectedImages", selectImages);
      Intent i = new Intent();
      i.putExtra("data", selectImages);
      setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, i);
      finish();
    }
  }
});
```

Any clues?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: ok thanks for immediately replay

Comment: https://www.ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-do-I-encode-single-pictures-into-movies_003f   may help u